# htaccess - remove parts from URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've been working on that for 2 days now. Reading everything I could find about .htaccess rewrite.
But I'm just not getting what I want.

Here's what I have:

```
http://www.domain.com/this/andthis/function.file-get-contents/
```

And this is what I need:

```
http://www.domain.com/this/andthis/
```

For some reason, the browser goes to `http://www.domain.com/`
My htaccess file contains these two lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)(function\.file-get-contents)
RewriteRule . $1 [R=301]
```

Also, I could not find what `%{REQUEST_URI}` is... I kinda feel stupid.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please be more specific -- what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to remove 3-rd folder from URL ... (any name) or this specific URL only)? Please clarify. **P.S.** browser goes to `http://www.domain.com/` because you told Apache to do so (that is what that rule does).

Comment: I just wanted to remove "/function.file-get-contents". Wordpress got that from somewhere and Google still crawls that stuff.
Floern's answer is the winner!

Comment: I'm glad that you have got working rule and had it fast. Next time try to be more specific straight away as both answers are correct considering your original request. Keep in mind that other people are unaware of your specific circumstances and may only guess what you actually really need.

Comment: You're right!
I wasn't aware that my question could be understood in such many ways! :)
Next time I'll try to be more, not over, but more specific.
Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)function\.file-get-contents $1 [L,R=301]
```

Here you don't need a RewriteCond.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/function\.file-get-contents $1/$2 [R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks but not quite!
I should've been more specific. It's not always the third item to remove... See answer from Floern.